# Call shell script with string, integer, string, string

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to call a shell script from Python using [Subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). When I call my script from terminal I use:

```
// Passing string, int, string, string
sh script.sh "firstArgument" 4040 "thirdArgument" "fourthArgument"
```

So, I thought this is the correct way to do this in Python using `subprocess`:

```
args = ['sh script.sh', "firstArgument", 3030, "thirdArgument", "fourthArgument"] 
val = subprocess.check_call(args, shell=True)
```

But when I run this code, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_console.py", line 129, in <module>
    app.main()
  File "main_console.py", line 34, in main
    val = subprocess.check_call(args, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 506, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

What can I do to send to my script these arguments without receive an error?

### Edit:

The problem isn't with the argument itself. I can send a integer to my script. The problem now is: when I run my sh from Terminal, like this:

```
sh script.sh "blabla" "400" "blabla" "blabla"
```

This works. But when I run my python file with this code:

```
 args = ['sh script.sh', "firstArgument", 3030, "thirdArgument", "fourthArgument"] 
 val = subprocess.check_call(args, shell=True)
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Removing proxy configuration.

(gconftool-2:28078): GConf-WARNING **: Failed to load source "xml:readwrite:/home/root/.gconf": Failed: Could not make directory `/home/root/.gconf': No such file or directory
**
GConf:ERROR:gconftool.c:969:main: assertion failed: (err == NULL)
Aborted

(gconftool-2:28079): GConf-WARNING **: Failed to load source "xml:readwrite:/home/root/.gconf": Failed: Could not make directory `/home/root/.gconf': No such file or directory
**
GConf:ERROR:gconftool.c:969:main: assertion failed: (err == NULL)
Aborted

(gconftool-2:28080): GConf-WARNING **: Failed to load source "xml:readwrite:/home/root/.gconf": Failed: Could not make directory `/home/root/.gconf': No such file or directory
**
GConf:ERROR:gconftool.c:969:main: assertion failed: (err == NULL)
Aborted

(gconftool-2:28081): GConf-WARNING **: Failed to load source "xml:readwrite:/home/root/.gconf": Failed: Could not make directory `/home/root/.gconf': No such file or directory
**
GConf:ERROR:gconftool.c:969:main: assertion failed: (err == NULL)
Aborted

(gconftool-2:28082): GConf-WARNING **: Failed to load source "xml:readwrite:/home/root/.gconf": Failed: Could not make directory `/home/root/.gconf': No such file or directory
**
GConf:ERROR:gconftool.c:969:main: assertion failed: (err == NULL)
Aborted

(gconftool-2:28083): GConf-WARNING **: Failed to load source "xml:readwrite:/home/root/.gconf": Failed: Could not make directory `/home/root/.gconf': No such file or directory
**
GConf:ERROR:gconftool.c:969:main: assertion failed: (err == NULL)
Aborted

(gconftool-2:28084): GConf-WARNING **: Failed to load source "xml:readwrite:/home/root/.gconf": Failed: Could not make directory `/home/root/.gconf': No such file or directory
**
GConf:ERROR:gconftool.c:969:main: assertion failed: (err == NULL)
Aborted

(gconftool-2:28085): GConf-WARNING **: Failed to load source "xml:readwrite:/home/root/.gconf": Failed: Could not make directory `/home/root/.gconf': No such file or directory
**
GConf:ERROR:gconftool.c:969:main: assertion failed: (err == NULL)
Aborted
```

Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: have you tried putting quotes around your 2nd arg to make it a string and see what happens? I've never come across this problem but I believe that should do the trick

Comment: When I do that I have a big error, I will update the question soon with the log.

Comment: Well, I try to do more test and the problem isn't with the arguments, is in the script itself. When I run sh from terminal don't have any issues, but when execute from python I have a lot of issues: `(gconftool-2:27531): GConf-WARNING **: Failed to load source "xml:readwrite:/home/root/.gconf": Failed: Could not make directory `/home/root/.gconf': No such file or directory
**
GConf:ERROR:gconftool.c:969:main: assertion failed: (err == NULL)
Aborted`

Comment: sounds like you have some path problems. Obviously I don't know what your paths and directories are, but make sure that all your path are set to the absolute path i.e. /User/Username/.../... not just from the current directory. Other than that, you're going to have to look at your paths and find the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check_call(['sh', 'script.sh', "firstArgument", '3030', "thirdArgument", "fourthArgument"])
```

If the number is in a variable, you need to make a string of it:

```
portNum = 3030
check_call(['sh', 'script.sh', "firstArgument", str(portNum), "thirdArgument", "fourthArgument"])
```

And **do not** use `shell=True`. Even though you're *invoking* a shell, `shell=True` should only be used when you want *the argument list itself* to be interpreted by a shell. Its use is almost universally the Wrong Thing.

Comment: If I remove shell=True, I receive another error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_console.py", line 129, in <module>
    app.main()
  File "main_console.py", line 34, in main
    val = subprocess.call(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Where I can put my script to solve this issue and how I can call him from Python?

Comment: @FernandoPaladini I'd suggest setting the `cwd` to the directory with the script, and using `'./script.sh'` as the second argument.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain better? What's cwd?

Comment: @FernandoPaladini `cwd` is an optional argument to `subprocess.Popen` and its friends (such as `check_call`).

Comment: But, how I can do that? Sorry... :(

Comment: @FernandoPaladini, `check_call([...], cwd='/path/to/directory/')`

Comment: Thanks, but now I receive "Permission denied". Following is my code: 
`args = ['./script.sh', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg3'] 
     val = subprocess.check_call(args,cwd='../script/')`

Comment: @FernandoPaladini There's nothing intrinsically wrong with the code you posted, so I can't help you with it here -- if the directory is one you don't have `+x` on, or isn't a directory at all, or if the script doesn't have `+rx`, or if its interpreter has the wrong permissions, or if it's in a directory on a filesystem mounted noexec... so on and so forth. That issue can't be diagnosed without a reproducer, or access to the system where it happens.